# Is there any way to workaround import version conflict ion issue caused by Pyxb

Tags: python, pyxb

I have 3 python projects. Project A, project B and project C. Project C depends on Porject A and B

```
Project C --- depends ---> Project A
Project C --- depends ---> Project B
```

And project A and project B all depends on [PyXB](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net), they use some generated schema module. Unfortunately, project A uses PyXB 1.2.2, and project B uses PyXB 1.2.3

```
Project A --- depends ---> PyXB 1.2.2
Project B --- depends ---> PyXB 1.2.3
```

If you read these modules, you will see

```
# Version of PyXB used to generate the bindings
_PyXBVersion = '1.2.3'
# Generated bindings are not compatible across PyXB versions
if pyxb.__version__ != _PyXBVersion:
    raise pyxb.PyXBVersionError(_PyXBVersion)
```

and

```
# Version of PyXB used to generate the bindings
_PyXBVersion = '1.2.2'
# Generated bindings are not compatible across PyXB versions
if pyxb.__version__ != _PyXBVersion:
    raise pyxb.PyXBVersionError(_PyXBVersion)
```

So, for now, Project C has a version conflict issue

```
Project C --- depends ---> PyXB 1.2.2
                                ^
                                |
                                X conflict
                                |
                                v
Project C --- depends ---> PyXB 1.2.3
```

And since these schema modules were manually modified. It's hard to regenerate them and apply the same modifications. So I am wondering is it possible to import the same module with different version in Python. For example, I envision that could be something like

```
with import_routing('pyxb', '..packages.pyxb1_2_3'):
    import project_a
```

is there a tool like this? or is there other workaround I can use in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.  The bindings really do make assumptions about the underlying API presented by a specific version of PyXB.  There's probably some magic you could do with modifying the module metadata to allow two versions to co-exist, as long as no document referenced bindings from both namespaces.

It's unfortunate that the generated bindings were manually modified.  In many cases, use of PyXB's [customization infrastructure](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_pyxbgen.html#customizing-binding-classes) would eliminate that tight coupling, in which case you could re-generate the bindings and re-use the customizations that overlay them.